# Best Alternative Of Property File In Java

Tags: java, properties, content-management-system

Hey I am working on the product which is live at multiple portals. The product is developed in GWT, JAVA, Hibernate.

**My question is :** Whether there is any alternative of using property file in java.

**My Requirement :**

1. For one property key there are multiple values in live portal for each different portal.
2. Each time I change property file, I need to make the war again.
3. The loading of any of the property should not be time-consuming.

Any help or suggession would be apprecialble !!!

Comment: You could load a key set into memory at regular intervals (15 min) or create some type of notification action to kickstart this process, and have all the systems point at a single database to get their properties.

Comment: There are about 15K properties that I need to add.. Making all of them DB Driven is also not helping me out..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lightweight key-value store, such as [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html).

If the portals are being hosted on multiple machines, then you can use a distributed key-value store, such as [Voldemort](http://www.project-voldemort.com/voldemort/).